# How to search vector element and replace it?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, vector, replace

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

void print(vector<string> v) {
   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
     cout << "[" << i << "] " << v[i] << "\n";
    }
 }

 int main(){
    vector<string> v(5);
    v[0] = "Egg";
    v[1] = "Milk";
    v[2] = "Sugar";
    v[3] = "Chocolate";
    v[4] = "Flour";

    print(v);

  system("pause");
}
```

How do I make a loop that searches for the item, "sugar" and replace it with "honey."? Sry, im new to vectors

Comment: What have you tried?  It looks like you know how to iterate through a vector and print it's elements and it is not to much different from that.

Comment: I've tried with insert, but failed.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace

Comment: A print function doesn't need a copy of the vector. Pass const reference.

Comment: I would suggest you either pick up a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list); or read the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for the classes you use more carefully.  Insert is clearly documented to just add a new item.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace specific values in a vector in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904976/how-to-replace-specific-values-in-a-vector-in-c)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to replace the first instance of the string (if it exists) you can use `std::find` then assign to the iterator that is returned.

```
std::vector<std::string> v {"Egg", "Milk", "Sugar", "Chocolate", "Flour"};

auto itMatch = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), "Sugar");
if (itMatch != v.end())
    *itMatch = "Honey";
```

If you'd like to replace all instances

```
std::replace(v.begin(), v.end(), "Sugar", "Honey");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard alfgorithm `std::find`. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::string> v = 
    {
        "Egg", "Milk", "Sugar", "Chocolate", "Flour"
    };

    const char *src = "Sugar";
    const char *dsn = "Honey";

    auto it = std::find( v.begin(), v.end(), src );

    if ( it != v.end() ) *it = dsn;

    for ( const auto &s : v ) std::cout << s << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Egg Milk Honey Chocolate Flour
```

If you want to replace all occurences of "Sugar" then you can use the standard algorithm `std::replace`.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::string> v = 
    {
        "Egg", "Milk", "Sugar", "Chocolate", "Flour", "Sugar"
    };

    const char *src = "Sugar";
    const char *dsn = "Honey";

    std::replace( v.begin(), v.end(), src, dsn );

    for ( const auto &s : v ) std::cout << s << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Egg Milk Honey Chocolate Flour Honey
```

If you mean the substitution only in the function `print` within the loop then the function can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

void print( const std::vector<std::string> &v, 
            const std::string &src = "Sugar", 
            const std::string &dsn = "Honey" ) 
{
    for ( std::vector<std::string>::size_type i = 0; i < v.size(); i++ )
    {
        std::cout << "[" << i << "] " << ( v[i] == src ? dsn : v[i] ) << "\n";
    }
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::string> v = 
    {
        "Egg", "Milk", "Sugar", "Chocolate", "Flour"
    };

    print( v );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
[0] Egg
[1] Milk
[2] Honey
[3] Chocolate
[4] Flour
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you explain this:                                                                  
    ( v[i] == src ? dsn : v[i] )

Comment: Also, can you explain this:                                                              
        `auto itr = find(staff.begin(), staff.end(), "Milk");
         if (itr != staff.begin()) staff.erase(itr);`                                     
             How does it work? I know it removes "Milk", but don't know how.

Comment: @НедялкоАнгелов This ( v[i] == src ? dsn : v[i] ) is an expression with the so-called ternary or conditional operator. If v[i] is equal to src then theresult of the expression is dsn otherwise v[i] itself.