# Find and replace elements from a vector by value

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector which contains data for different groups. If I insert new data for a particular group into a vector it should replace the old data with a new one for the same group number. For this particular example std::replace gives an error

> std::replace: no matching overloaded function found

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class data
{
    public:
        int group;
        bool condition;
        friend bool operator==(const data& lhs, const data& rhs);
        data(int g, bool c) 
        {
            group = g;
            condition = c;
        }
};

bool  operator==(const data& lhs, const data& rhs)
{
     return lhs.group == rhs.group;
}

int main()
{
    data info_1(1, true);
    data info_2(2, true);
    data info_3(3, false);
    data info_4(4, false);
    data info_5(3, false); 

    std::vector<data> data_vector;

    data_vector.push_back(info_1);
    data_vector.push_back(info_2);
    data_vector.push_back(info_3);
    data_vector.push_back(info_4);

    if (std::find(data_vector.begin(), data_vector.end(), info_5) != data_vector.end())
    {
        std::cout << " Matched: \n";
        std::replace(data_vector.begin(), data_vector.end(), data_vector, info_5);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Not Matched: \n";
    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps `std::vector` is not the correct container type? Perhaps you should use e.g. [`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) (with a suitable [`std::hash`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) specialization)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, or perhaps std::map ? Is there any tradeoff ?

Comment: `std::replace` - third argument is an unary predicate or a value for comparisons ([see here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace)) and not a `std::vector` object.

Comment: Or `std::unordered_map`... And a map (ordered or unordered) might be better here really, as then you can have the `group` as a key and the data as the data.

Comment: check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904976/how-to-replace-specific-values-in-a-vector-in-c?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, this requires to implement a hash algorithm too for user-defined data types. Is there a easy way for this conversion ?

Comment: `std::replace(data_vector.begin(), data_vector.end(), data_vector, info_5);` this line seems to be wrong, replace it with  `std::replace(data_vector.begin(), data_vector.end(), info_2, info_5);`

Comment: `std::unordered_map<int, data>` doesn't, since one already exists for `int`.

Comment: @HarshGiri, what if I dont know the exact position of the element to be replaced?

Comment: The third parameter in **std::replace(data_vector.begin(), data_vector.end(), data_vector, info_5);** should be of type **data** instead of vector. You may do something like: **std::replace(data_vector.begin(), data_vector.end(), info_X, info_5);**

Answer (score 4):

This is modified version of your code. You should use iterator to get whats returned by find() and if its valid then pass it to replace() -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class data
{
    public:
        int group;
        bool condition;
        friend bool operator==(const data& lhs, const data& rhs);
        data(int g, bool c) 
        {
            group = g;
            condition = c;
        }
};

bool  operator==(const data& lhs, const data& rhs)
{
     return lhs.group == rhs.group;
}

int main()
{
    data info_1(1, true);
    data info_2(2, true);
    data info_3(3, false);
    data info_4(4, false);
    data info_5(3, false); 

    std::vector<data> data_vector;

    data_vector.push_back(info_1);
    data_vector.push_back(info_2);
    data_vector.push_back(info_3);
    data_vector.push_back(info_4);

    std::vector<data>::iterator it = std::find(data_vector.begin(), data_vector.end(), info_5);

    if ( it != data_vector.end())
    {
        std::cout << " Matched: " << info_5.group << std::endl;
        std::replace(data_vector.begin(), data_vector.end(), *it, info_5);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Not Matched: \n";
    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're overthinking this. `std::replace` is exactly what you want:

```
std::replace(data_vector.begin(), data_vector.end(), info_5, info_5);
```

This looks a bit odd, because it's replacing `info_5` with `info_5`, but that's because `operator==` for this type is a bit odd -- it only looks at the group value, so it will find the copy of `info_3` and replace it with `info_5`.

Now, that's maybe overkill, because it will look for every occurrence of `info_5` in the vector and replace them all. In many cases there's just one matching value; you can use `std::find` to find it, and then just assign a new value:

```
auto iter = std::find(data_vector.begin(), data_vector.end(), info_5);
if (iter != data_vector.end())
    *iter = replacement_value;
```

On the other hand, if you really only want one entry for each group, you're probably better off with `std::map`. To replace the **value** associated with a **group**, just look up the group and assign to it. With an object named `data_map` of type `std::map<int, bool>` that's had values assigned to it, all you need to do is:

```
data_map[3] = false;
```

However, if there is no entry with a group of 3, this will add one. If that's not what you want, you'll have to check first:

```
auto iter = data_map.find(3);
if (iter != data_map.end())
    *iter = replacement_value;
```

Comment: Thanks! it is very helpful.

Comment: @ZeeshanHayat -- you should usually wait a day or so before accepting an answer. Someone might write a better one; for example, I didn't mention `std::set`, which is a better match than `std::map` for your `data` class, because it will deal with it unchanged, and might be a better fit.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, that you use a `std::map` for your purpose.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

void insert_or_assign (std::map<int, bool> &data, const std::pair <int, bool> item){
    auto search = data.find(item.first);
    if(search != data.end()) {
        data.erase(search);
    }
    data.insert(item);
}

int main() {
    std::map<int, bool> data;

    data.insert(std::pair <int, bool> (1, true));
    data.insert(std::pair <int, bool> (2, true));
    data.insert(std::pair <int, bool> (3, true));
    data.insert(std::pair <int, bool> (4, false));
    data.insert(std::pair <int, bool> (5, false));

     insert_or_assign(data, std::pair <int, bool> (5, true));
     insert_or_assign(data, std::pair <int, bool> (6, true));

    for (const auto &item : data) {
       std::cout << item.first << " " <<item.second << "\n";
    }
}
```

This gives the output

```
1 1
2 1
3 1
4 0
5 1
6 1
```

If you have a c++17 compiler you  can directly use `std::map::insert_or_assign`